# ios - UIActivityViewController: SMS option not showing

Tags: ios, sms, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to allow sharing by Mail, Facebook, Twitter and SMS. I have the following code:

```
-(void) aFunction
{
NSString *textToShare = appRecord.title;
UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test/png"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:textToShare, imageToShare,url,nil];


UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];

NSArray *applicationActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activity, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                  applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint ,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeMessage ];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
[activityItems release];
[activity release];
[applicationActivities release];
[activity release];
}
```

The code produces the following:

http://s24.postimg.org/tas3zo9w5/Screen_Shot_2013_10_01_at_5_09_26_PM.png

The SMS option is missing. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are excluding UIActivityTypeMessage (excludedActivityTypes). This hides the Messages (SMS/iMessage) option

Comment: Another thing is that the device must have capability for SMS for the option to appear.

Comment: Thanks @Ketan.  I was wondering why the Simulator wasn't showing that option but my QA device was.